# Ошибка выполнения, подозрение на выход за пределы памяти

Tags: c

Есть стандартный поток, нужно разбить его на слова и вывести эти слова в кавычках. В стандартном потоке слова разделены пробелами(их может быть и несколько)
Пример:
Входные данные

aaa    xb
cd

Результат работы

"aaa"
"cd"
"xb"

Вот мой код, но где-то скорее всего выход за пределы памяти, потому что валится на одном тесте с ошибкой выполнения. Помогите пожалуйста выяснить в чем проблема

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2);

int main() {
    char **ans = NULL, *buffer = NULL;
    int ch, currentSize = 0, size = 0;
    buffer = malloc(1);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        perror("");
        exit(0);
    }
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '*') {
        if (isspace(ch)) {
            if (currentSize != 0) {
                ans = realloc(ans, (size + 1) * sizeof(char*));
                if (ans == NULL) {
                    perror("");
                    exit(0);
                } else {
                    buffer[currentSize] = '\0';
                    ans[size++] = buffer;
                    buffer = malloc(1);
                    if (buffer == NULL) {
                        perror("");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    currentSize = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            buffer = realloc(buffer, currentSize + 1);
            if (buffer == NULL) {
                perror("");
                exit(0);
            } else {
                buffer[currentSize++] = ch;
            }
        }
    }
    if (currentSize != 0) {
        ans = realloc(ans, (size + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        if (ans == NULL) {
            perror("");
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            buffer[currentSize] = '\0';
            ans[size++] = buffer;
        }
    } else {
        free(buffer);
    }

    qsort(ans, size, sizeof(char*), cmp);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("\"%s\"\n", ans[i]);
        free(ans[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    return strcmp(* (char * const *) p1, * (char * const *) p2);
}
```

Comment: `buffer = malloc(1);` - зачем это делается вообще? Почему не просто `buffer = NULL;`?

Comment: a так не возникнут проблемы?

Comment: Из-за чего именно?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде запись замыкающего символа `\0` в каждое слово всегда делается с выходом за пределы массива.

В момент, когда вы делаете

```
buffer[currentSize] = '\0';
```

размер выделенной памяти у вас всегда равен строго `currentSize`. То есть налицо очевидный вылет за пределы массива.